# SQL Server import csv file to table -Messing the columns in table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

Hi iam importring the data from .csv file to table.
i have first columns in the csv file is

```
California    COOL
Houston       HOT     
Dalla,TX      HOT
```

after ssis package the data in the table is looking like

```
California  COOL
Houston     HOT
Dalla       TX,HOT
```

I am unable to figure out my problem, can you help me guys ?

Comment: So your data is tab delimited instead of comma?

Comment: Change the last value to "aaa,d" with the double quotes.

Comment: i cant change the data csv file consists of million rows and 5% of data is in that format.

Comment: @VasanthSundaralingam in my csv file first column consists of

Comment: What exactly is the column delimiter?  Assuming your second field is an integer, you can try to validate it to be an integer. If it is not an integer, try to parse it. If you tell us the column delimiter, we can offer more precise solution.

Comment: @AnoopVerma  iam using comma {,} for first column..the column consists of both data as chicago and houston,TX ..sorry my second field is also a varchar

Answer (score 0):

You need to open that Data Flow task for editing and then open Flat File Source which is used for csv file. In the Flat file connection manager editor, select Advanced tab, and then change the column delimiter to Tab from ,. Here is the reference link for the same. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/12/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-database-table-using-ssis/